# Logistic regression in R: Handling mixed numerical and categorical variables

Tags: r, regression, logistic, categorical-encoding

I'm attempting to fit a logistic regression model in R and need some guidance on handling both numerical and categorical variables simultaneously, especially when looking for significant explanatory variables.

**Background**

I have a dataset named df containing 12 columns in R. My response variable, renewal, is binary with values indicating whether a customer renewed their insurance policy (1) or not (0). The other 11 variables are potential predictors. Among them, 4 are categorical: AccInsurance, ProdNumber, CompNumber, and LivingForm. I converted these categorical variables into factors using the following R code:

```
df$AccInsurance <- as.factor(df$AccInsurance)
df$ProdNumber <- as.factor(df$ProdNumber)
df$CompNumber <- as.factor(df$CompNumber)
df$LivingForm <- as.factor(df$LivingForm).
```

I'm seeking to determine the significance of each explanatory variable in predicting the renewal outcome.

**Challenges**

**Significance Testing:** I proceeded to fit a logistic regression model using the following code:

```
logit_model <- glm(renewal ~., data = df, family = binomial)
```

However, upon looking at the summary output, I noticed coefficients for individual categories within categorical variables (e.g., ProdNumber50, ProdNumber51, etc.), rather than the overall significance of the categorical variable itself. What can I do in order to see the overall significance of the categorical variable? I want to do this analysis in order to know of I should keep all the explanatory variables or remove some that are not statistically significant.

Is my approach using `drop1(logit_model, test = "Chisq")` or `Anova(logit_model, type = "II")` to do this appropriate for assessing the significance of explanatory variables, or is there a better method?

**The summary**

```
summary(logit_model)
 
Call:
glm(formula = renewal ~ ., family = binomial,
    data = df)
 
Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)       -3.588e-02  1.629e-02  -2.203  0.02760 * 
System            -7.961e-03  5.833e-02  -0.136  0.89144   
ProdNumber50       7.599e-02  8.896e-03   8.543  < 2e-16 ***
ProdNumber51       1.741e-01  3.583e-02   4.859 1.18e-06 ***
ProdNumber52       1.902e-01  2.321e-02   8.195 2.51e-16 ***
ProdNumber53       2.664e-01  2.697e-02   9.875  < 2e-16 ***
CompNumber        -2.713e-03  4.449e-04  -6.099 1.07e-09 ***
AccInsurance1      3.769e-02  1.204e-02   3.130  0.00175 **
AccInsurance2      2.736e-01  2.604e-02  10.507  < 2e-16 ***
AccInsurance3      4.065e-01  8.223e-03  49.436  < 2e-16 ***
LivingForm             NA         NA      NA       NA   
Duration           8.050e-02  9.783e-04  82.285  < 2e-16 ***
NoCars            -8.314e-04  3.769e-04  -2.206  0.02740 * 
VAge               5.461e-03  4.177e-04  13.075  < 2e-16 ***
OAge               1.311e-03  7.063e-05  18.565  < 2e-16 ***
Moment             2.497e-01  4.009e-03  62.280  < 2e-16 ***
YrPremium.        -2.635e-05  1.404e-06 -18.771  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 
(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
 
    Null deviance: 646530  on 590043  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 623236  on 590028  degrees of freedom
AIC: 623268
 
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

**Conclusion**

In summary, I seek clarification on if my method for assessing the significance of explanatory variables in logistic regression is correct. Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Anova test will answer your question about a given predictor's overall statistical significance.  There are several ways to obtain additional useful information.  Set up a model with and without a given predictor, or a series of models in which successive predictors are included.  Then compare, for each model:

1. AIC or the Akaike Information Criterion, which helps assess the tradeoff between predictive performance and parsimony
2. McFadden's pseudo-R-squared, via 1 - (residual deviance)/(null deviance)
3. An alternative pseudo-R-squared:  the squared correlation between predicted and observed values of the outcome.